# How to use SearchCriteria Builder for the Magento2 orders between two dates

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How can I convert following M1 code to M2 code using SearchCriteria Builder.

**Note**: api_status is a custom column in *sales_order* table

```
    $dateTo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    // 1 hour before current time
    $dateFrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 3600);

    $orderFrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateFrom));
    $orderTo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateTo));

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $orderFrom, 'to' => $orderTo))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('api_status', array('eq' => '2'));
```

If I do not want to use following code.

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
   
)
{
 
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
}

$collection = $this->orderCollectionFactory()->create()
     ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $orderFrom, 'to' => $orderTo))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('api_status', array('eq' => '2')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using search criteria it will look like this:

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $dateTo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $dateFrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 3600);

        $orderFrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateFrom));
        $orderTo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateTo));

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter('created_at', $orderFrom, 'gteq')
            ->addFilter('created_at', $orderTo, 'lteq')
            ->addFilter('api_status', 2, 'eq')
            ->create();

        $items = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.